# MapBox SDK not working android

Tags: android, mapbox

I just started to use the MapBox SDK but its not working I was following the steps on the documentation but Im not getting any classes from their SDK here is my code:

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapp.hello"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.0-beta.2@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.mapp.hello"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService` is shown in red and I cannot import the `MapboxAccountManager`

Comment: You may need to add a refernce to MAS or Mapbox Android Services.   `compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how but the app was getting run even though gradle build was stopped because of lint, I just stopped lint from stopping the build process now everything is working :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I just had the same error while trying to update from Mapbox 4.x to 5.x and it turns out you have to change:

`<service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService"/>`

to

```
<service android:name="com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.service.TelemetryService" />
```

**Update**:
Turns out in the latest version (5.x) you don't have to declare it in the Manifest at all, as Mapbox now makes use of Manifest merge feature.